# Video becomes 'Not Responding' while using wxpython in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, windows-10, wxpython

I am trying to build a Gesture controlled Cursor. For that I need wxpython library. I am using my webcam for recognizing a gesture and assigning cursor to it. I am trying to make a 'V' sign in front of webcam while wearing green finger caps. The color recognition and gesture recognition code is working fine, but after assigning the cursor ( using wxpython ) my video goes "not responding" every time !

**This code is working fine on mac when I am running it from terminal using wpython <file_name.py> .But it is giving me a issue on my Windows 10 laptop.** Please help me rectify this issue !

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import wx

#Global Vairiable Declarations we will need:
mouse=Controller()
app=wx.App(False)
(sx,sy)=wx.GetDisplaySize()
(camx,camy)=(320,240)
pinchFlag=0
#We weill have to consider all green colors.We will work in HSV format.
lowerBound=np.array([33,80,40])
upperBound=np.array([102,255,255])


#lowerBound = np.array([25, 52, 72])
#upperBound = np.array([102, 255, 255])

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
kernelOpen = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
kernelClose = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)

while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    img = cv2.resize(img,(340,220))
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lowerBound,upperBound)
    
    Opening =cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
    Closing =cv2.morphologyEx(Opening,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)
    FinalMask = Closing
    
    conts,h=cv2.findContours(FinalMask.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cv2.drawContours(img,conts,-1,(255,0,0),3)
    
    for i in range(len(conts)):
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)
        #cv2.PutText(img, str(i+1),(x,y+h),font,(0,255,255))
        
    if (len(conts)==2):
        x1,y1,w1,h1 =cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
        x2,y2,w2,h2 =cv2.boundingRect(conts[1])
        cx1 = (x1+w1)/2
        cy1 = (y1+h1)/2
        cx2 = (x2+w2)/2
        cy2 = (y2+h2)/2
        
        #FINAL MOUSE CO-ORDINATES AND PLOTTING THEM:
        
        x_final = int((cx1 + cx2)/2)
        y_final = int((cy1 + cy2)/2)
        cx1 = int(cx1)
        cx2 = int(cx2)
        cy1 = int(cy1)
        cy2 = int(cy2)
        
        cv2.line(img, (cx1,cy1),(cx2,cy2),(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.circle(img, (x_final,y_final),2,(0,0,255),2)
        
        #ASSIGNING MOUSE TO (X_FINAL,Y_FINAL):
        
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        mouseLoc=(sx-(x_final*sx/camx), y_final*sy/camy)
        mouse.position=mouseLoc
        while mouse.position!=mouseLoc: 
            pass
            #This loop will just wait till our cursor reaches the desired location.      
        
    elif(len(conts)==1):
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        x_final=int(x+w/2)
        y_final=int(y+h/2)
        cv2.circle(img,(x_final,y_final),int((w+h)/4),(0,0,255),2)
       
        if pinchFlag == 0:
            pinchFlag = 1
            mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouseLoc=(sx-(x_final*sx/camx), y_final*sy/camy)
        mouse.position=mouseLoc 
        while mouse.position!=mouseLoc: 
            pass
    
    #cv2.imshow("Closing",Closing)
    #cv2.imshow("Opening",Opening)
    #cv2.imshow("mask",mask)
    cv2.imshow("cam",img)
    #if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        #break
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: What is the given issue(error) you mentioned ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk There is no error displayed ! The video tab which is opened goes to not responding mode....  The video freezes

Comment: Are you using python multithreading? If the answer is NO, that is the answer to your problem.
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/